# Can't get JWT based security in .NET Core 3.0 working

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, .net-core-3.0

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#addidentityserverjwt), I'm supposed to be able to use the following.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

This doesn't work because `AddIdentityServerJwt` seem not to be there. Also, I'm not sure if I want to go hand in hand with IdentityServer at this moment at all.

I haven't found any tutorials or blogs discussing security for an SPA based on backend in .NET Core 3.0 that wouldn't be [a direct referrer](http://dotnetdetail.net/asp-net-core-3-0-web-api-token-based-authentication-example-using-jwt-in-vs2019/) to the link above (hence relying in the Identity Server). Probably because it such a cutting edge tech at the moment. The [migration manual from 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) is not exhausting and I also suspect that [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#security-middleware-guidance) might be [inaccurate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorization).

In previous version, I'd declare a default scheme and configure the token validation in the Startup.cs file. However, now, it seems like all the cheese has been moved around in Core 3.

**How should I configure the (simplest possible) security using JWT and (most preferably) avoiding Identity Server?**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddAuthentication();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  ...
  //app.UseRouting();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  //app.UseAuthorization();
  //app.UseEndpoints(e => e.MapControllers());
}
```

This produces different variations of the following error in Swagger.

> No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have to use .NET Core 3? It is still in preview and it's likely that external packages like Swagger have not been updated to support it? I would check and make sure whether Swagger supports .NET Core 3.0. Also if this is for an application that is supposed to go into production, do not (yet) use .NET Core 3!

Comment: @TobiasTengler While fully prepared for certain turbulence due to the preview status of the framwork, I wish to be the first man on the ball, so to speak. Preview means that it's not finnished but also that most of the stuff is ready. There seem to be principal changes to how the security is implemented. And since MS has released the docs on how to migrate, I think it's important to explore the new stuff. (As for the Swagger, you're partially right. I got it working even if I had to do a hackaroo.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing part is that right after calling `AddAuthentication`, you also need to explicitly "optin" into JWT bearer:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer();
}
```

At the moment, that operation requires a manual installation of the extension methods as shown [here](Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer -Version 3.0.0-preview6.19307.2).

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer -Version 3.0.0-preview6.19307.2

The [documentation for Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0) covering the method, redirects at the moment to its counterpart for Core 2.2 and may be updated or removed at any time, due to the preview state.

Comment: Once I got some sleep and retried, your post gave me the exact push to my aha-moment. Kind of stupid I didn't realize it previously but better late than never, right? I took the liberty to push in the missing parts into your question (I believe answering ones own questions is tacky). What I wonder, though, is if you got that method automagically in your project? Are you doing Core 3.0 or an earlier version?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed the part with the separate package. I have a side project with 3.0 - there are a lot of breaking changes comparing to previous version.

Comment: Can you recall what other packages you had to manually push into the side project? The MSDN is rather unhelpful on the subject and it seems to me like a waste of time to discover those oopsies one by one...

Comment: I'm actually running there against IdentityServer, so its probably won't be helpful for you. I have `IdentityModel` and `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` packages, the rest coming from  "shared framework".